# use collect() method to report same day collection data

Tags: java, groovyshell

Question, Id like to use the java collect() method to search a database collection for collections on the same-day.

Example, this won't work below because the time is factored in I believe, so is there another way to compare just the date just using the collect method?

```
Invoice invoice= new Invoice();
List<Receipt> receipts= invoice.collect("receipts[createdDate==#p1]", new Date())
```

Comment: What is your exact question? what is "till"?

Comment: I revised it above for humanize.  Basically, I just need a way to use the collect method to compare a date field to the same-day, so I can extract  collection entries that match the current day.

Comment: You want to apply collect over Invoice or on the List<Invoice>?

Comment: Basically this is just an example. This example just searches the invoice receipt collection and returns all receipts for the current day. However, it won't work because you can't just compare 2 date types because of the time. My question is not focused on how the collect method works per say, but more on how to compare 2 dates in the collect() call to only return receipt entries based on the same-day.  There's a method called DateUtils.isSameDay(), but I'm trying to do this all in the collect() method call if possible. Maybe it just isn't possible, not sure.